# How to update content type field programmatically

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I try to update content type field `MYFIELD` with code

```
$update = db_update('field_data_field_MYFIELD')
    -> fields(array('field_MYFIELD_value' => $result))
    -> condition('entity_id', $nid)
    -> execute();
```

I see changes in database but they not reflected in node view. Also I applied this code to `field_revision_field_MYFIELD`table and got the same result. How can I update `MYFIELD` programmatically?

Comment: If your database is updated but the changes are not reflected in the node view, I would suggest first trying to clear all cache. But as sam2de said it is better to use the Drupal API for changes to field data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better( and simpler) solution is using with drupal [Node load](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load/7) and [Node save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) API

```
$node=node_load($nid);
$node->field_data_field_MYFIELD['und'][0]['value'];
node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use Drupa API to do that instead of missing with the database directly. you can use [field_attach_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_update/7) to update your field value

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$field = field_language('node', $node, 'field_your_field');
$node->field[$field_language][0]['value'] = 'Your New value';
field_attach_update('node', $node);
```